# calling jquery from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display(id)
{
  // open jquery modal window using jquery UI 
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to open jquery modal window using jquery UI whenever the function display is called using normal javascript function call .

I can use .diolog function of jquery UI  , but how to call it from within javascript function ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that jQuery *is* Javascript. What you can do with Javascript, you can do with jQuery.

Comment: And to be more precise: jQuery is a JavaScript *framework*.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a selector and call `.dialog()`, like this:

```
function display(id)
{
  $("#"+id).dialog();
}
```

This uses the passed `id` for the [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) then just calls [`.dialog()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for that element.